# Rebuilds with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

Visual Studio 2010 is known for causing missed or unwanted rebuilds. Both are annoying. There are numerous posts on the topic.

I have observed that whenever you switch the Configuration or the Platform, the next Build will be a Rebuild. For the same reason, a Batch Build always performs a full Batch Rebuild.

So my question is specifically: is there a way to avoid that, after a switch (Configuration or Platform), the build turns to a rebuild.

Comment: If I install a fresh Visual Studio 2010 (w/o any service pack), create an empty C# console app, build in Release and Debug, then I can switch configuration from release and debug back and forth and run build again, the output binaries don't change, so there's no rebuild, even if I quit and reopen Visual Studio (only the .vshost.exe changes). How do you reproduce this issue exactly? Are you sure it's not coming from some 3rd party?

Comment: @SimonMourier: for instance, Build All results in a Rebuild All every time. No third party software at all.

Comment: There's no "Build All" In Visual Studio 2010. But even if you mean "Build Solution", I can't reproduce. I've recorded a video where we can see the binaries are not rebuilt. https://1drv.ms/v/s!AsmmEDGvydk2lC7OknNm3NKsG-BL

Comment: @SimonMourier: I mean Batch Build > Build. But what's the use of proving me that you don't have this problem ?

Comment: Sorry, just trying to help

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is the intermediate directory for each configuration/platform? Is it possible that every configuration/platform output their object file in the same directory?

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé: Bingo ! The Platform field was missing in the properties, causing the Win32 and x64 to share the Intermediate Directory. Now the problem is gone, thank you so much ! Feel free to enter this as an answer to get the bounty.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Glad that I could help you! I will enter my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the question comments, the problem comes from the "Intermediate Directory" pointing to same directory for every platform/configuration. The object files are then outputted in the same directory and creates conflicts when you change the configuration/platform, thus forcing a rebuild.

To avoid this problem, I recommend setting the Intermediate Directory to something like this:

```
$(SolutionDir)build\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\
```